# Play the movie faster with cvlc

Tags: shortcut-keys, vlc

I have seen that I can control the speed of vlc by using the keyboard shortcuts +/-. It works to play the movie slower with [-], but I can't get it to play faster than 1.00x with the [+] keyboard shortcut. This is with vlc run as `cvlc file.mkv` version 2.0.3-0ubuntu0 under Ubuntu 12.04 x86.

I am doing this on a laptop, so the only '+' sign I have is in the [+/=] key.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

Use the square brackets keys.

- `[` for decrease speed by 0.1x increments
- `]` for increase speed by
  0.1x increments

These keys also allow moving above the 1.0x speed, unlike +/- keys.

Answer (score 3):

- Try the <kbd>+</kbd> key on the numeric keypad. This seems to increase the playback rate by 0.5. I found this out by
  trying every key on my keyboard :) (<kbd>-</kbd> slows the playback
  rate.)
- Try the <kbd>=</kbd> key. This seems to increase the playback rate by
  0.1. Note that cvlc seems to assume a **QWERTY** keyboard layout, regardless of your choice of keyboard layout.
- On Ubuntu 11.10, there is a config file for vlc located at
  `~/.config/vlc/vlcrc`. Search for

  ```
  # Faster (fine) (key)
  # key-rate-faster-fine=]
  ```

  and / or

  ```
  # Faster (key)
  # key-faster=+
  ```

  Uncomment the second line by removing the `#` sign, and (if you desire) change the key. For example,

  ```
     # Faster (key)
     key-faster=0
  ```

Comment: hmmm, I am doing this on a laptop, so the only '+' sign I have is in the [+/=] key...

Comment: I can't get `cvlc` to pick up any changes I make to the `~/.config/vlc/vlcrc` file.

Comment: @olejorgenb same thing here. you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Hotkeys map http://openclipart.org/detail/171818/keyboard-mappings-for-clvc-by-todd-partridge---gen2ly-171818

Official documentation: https://wiki.videolan.org/Hotkeys_table/

Answer (score 0):

You are expected to use square brackets.
They are usually found under the <kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>+</kbd> key on the keyboard.

<kbd>[</kbd> - For decreasing the speed of video

<kbd>]</kbd> - For increasing the speed

http://www.latestsolution.com/2016/07/top-20-keyboard-shortcut-vlc.html